# How to use RenderTargetBitmap in RunTime Components using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-10-universal

When I call the component from JavaScript. Showing an error(an unhandled expection win32). I have used RenderTargetBitmap in RunTime Components for Windows 10 Universal Apps. For more please refer to the following code.

```
public void Hello() { Task.Run(() => { buttonClick(); }); }
public async void buttonClick()
{
    await SaveImageAsync(Window.Current.Content);
}
private async static Task<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveImage(UIElement ele)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ele);
    return renderTargetBitmap;
}
public static IAsyncOperation<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveImageAsync(UIElement ele)
{
    return SaveImage(ele).AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, RenderTargetBitmap api is not available in Javascript. `RenderTargetBitmap` is a Xaml class and renders only Xaml. If you accessed, it will throw [invalid signature error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/diagnosing-windows-runtime-component-error-conditions#exporting-types-that-arent-valid-universal-windows-platform-types). For more you could refer to [`RenderTargetBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap) Class.

Comment: public sealed class ScreenCapture
    {
       
      public void Hello()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                buttonClick();
            });
        }

        public async void buttonClick()
        {
            await SaveImageAsync();
        }

Comment: private async static Task<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveImage()
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Window.Current.Content);
            return renderTargetBitmap;
        }

        public static IAsyncOperation<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveImageAsync()
        {
            return SaveImage().AsAsyncOperation();
        }

    }
     
}

Comment: Hello method is a RunTimeComponent class which is invoked from the javascript file. when i invoked the Hello()  I am getting the exception as an unhandled win32 exception occurred in WWAHost.exe

Comment: Is there any other way to capture the screen content from javascript?